# Adding a line in vim adds it at the line after the cursor, I would like to insert

Tags: vim

I have this keybinding in `.vimrc`:

```
map + :put=''<cr>
map - dd
```

I find it really useful for fast layout and source file cleaning with <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd>.

But using `:put=""<cr>` adds a line after the current cursor line, whereas `dd` removes a line at the current cursor.

I'd rather have my <kbd>+</kbd> keybinding insert a line rather than add it after. What command should I try ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Reading it again I gather I misunderstood. But, what about:

```
-put
```

It inserts line above current.

Edit:

As do:

```
 put!
```

To insert at mark (m[a-z]) one can say `'aput=xx`, `'bput=xx` etc.

Comment: after your correction `-put` is ok. However I don't have understood the difference between `.put` and `put`.

Comment: @StephaneRolland: AFAIK they are the same. As is +0put and -0put. If you do not know one also have $put as last line, 0put to NNput for line specific. +1put two down, +2put three down -3put three up etc. Believe one can also put on marks, but have to check that.

Answer (score 3):

Why not `O<Esc>`?

```
:map + O<Esc>
```

Comment: ...but it also makes vim switch and reswitch of mode.

Comment: @StephaneRolland, So does `:put`. (normal <-> cmd), why does that matter?

Comment: just because I thought vim was slow to change of mode, but I have just checked, and that doesn't seem to be the case.